# Authorization problem in Android with glassfish

Tags: android, apache, http

I'm writing an HTTP client in Android that connects to glassfish on my localhost and sends some json information to the server.

I use:

```
UsernamePasswordCredentials cred =
      new UsernamePasswordCredentials(SettingsHelper.mUser, SettingsHelper.mPwd);
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, cred);
```

for authontication, and making a put request. 
The problem is sometimes, the client sends an unauthorized request before retrying and sending an authorized one, and on the second time, it pushes the json entity, before getting a proper response from the server (100 - continue). then, the server doesn't respond at all, and everything hangs.

i will note that sometimes it works.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?  How might I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

finally managed to make it work with basic pre-emptive authontication.

[example here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication.java)